# How to get password and email from Asp.net membership in asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a small mvc3 web application in that i want get the forget password and email that password How can i customize code for that forgret password in mvc3 ... Plase help me.

Comment: The way asp.net authentication is setup normally is that the password is hashed in the database which means you cannot unhash it, for security reasons. That is why you should rather regenerate a random password for the user and email him that with the option to change it once he has logged in

Comment: Hi thank you for giving responce.How can i regenarate the password and send the email can u give any idea please....

Comment: I've given you 2 links that should be able to provide you with enough info, let me know if you don't come right

Comment: The one I have been looking into is here:
[Implement Password Recovery in ASP.NET MVC 2][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793108/where-to-find-c-sharp-sample-code-to-implement-password-recovery-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: The one I have been looking into is here:
[Implement Password Recovery in ASP.NET MVC 2][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793108/where-to-find-c-sharp-sample-code-to-implement-password-recovery-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: The one I have been looking into is here:
[Implement Password Recovery in ASP.NET MVC 2][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793108/where-to-find-c-sharp-sample-code-to-implement-password-recovery-in-asp-net-mvc