# how to fix CspParameters not supported by Mono exception calling CryptDeriveKey

Tags: c#, .net, mono, cryptography, security

I try to port ASP .NET MVC2 password recovery code from [Where to find C# sample code to implement password recovery in ASP .NET MVC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793108/where-to-find-c-sharp-sample-code-to-implement-password-recovery-in-asp-net-mvc) answer to Mono.
I it contains procedure below. CryptDeriveKey call causes exception in Mono

```
CspParameters not supported by Mono
```

How to implement password recovery in Mono in ASP .NET MVC2 application ?

```
    /// <summary> 
    /// Takes a text message and encrypts it using a password as a key. 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="plainMessage">A text to encrypt.</param> 
    /// <param name="password">The password to encrypt the message with.</param> 
    /// <returns>Encrypted string.</returns> 
    /// <remarks>This method uses TripleDES symmmectric encryption.</remarks> 
    public static string EncodeMessageWithPassword(string plainMessage, string password)
    {
        if (plainMessage == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("encryptedMessage", "The message cannot be null");

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        des.IV = new byte[8];

        //Creates the key based on the password and stores it in a byte array. 
        PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, new byte[0]);
        // in mono CryptDeriveKey causes exception:
        // CspParameters not supported by Mono
        des.Key = pdb.CryptDeriveKey("RC2", "MD5", 128, new byte[8]);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(plainMessage.Length * 2);
        CryptoStream encStream = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        byte[] plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainMessage);
        encStream.Write(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
        encStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[ms.Length];
        ms.Position = 0;
        ms.Read(encryptedBytes, 0, (int)ms.Length);
        encStream.Close();

        return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot *fix* this as the type `CspParameters` is not *really* supported by Mono.

The reason is that this type is used to communicate extra information between the (managed) BCL code and the CryptoAPI's CSP (crypto service provider). Since Mono use only managed code and that CryptoAPI is not available outside Windows then the `CspParameters` class is mostly a stub, a definition without code.

In particular the type [`PasswordDeriveBytes`](http://kipunji.jpobst.com/kipunji/mscorlib.dll/System.Security.Cryptography.PasswordDeriveBytes) is a bit special. It implements the standard PKCS#5 v1.5, which Mono supports, but it also adds a few Microsoft [extensions](http://kipunji.jpobst.com/System.Security.Cryptography.PasswordDeriveBytes.GetBytes) (breaking the specification) including one one them being [totally](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=372893) [broken](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=372893) (security wise). You should take great care when using `PasswordDeriveBytes`.

The case for `CryptDeriveKey` is even more badly designed. It has nothing to do with (any version of) PKCS#5, like the rest of `PasswordDeriveBytes` (i.e. it's not standard-based). What it does is simply redirect your parameters to CryptoAPI using the default CSP. Some majors issues arise form this:

1. AFAIK Microsoft never published the algorithm(s) they are using to derive keys in *their* CSP. I can't say if it's even secure, their PKCS#5 extensions were not;
2. The "default" CSP can be changed (e.g. by applications) to default to a non-Microsoft CSP (e.g. hardward/smartcard CSP). The key derivation algorithm provided by those CSP is unknown (hopefully they call back into MS CSP);
3. CryptoAPI and the CSP are only available on Windows and differs by the version of Windows/exportability, not the version of the .NET framework.

You should avoid using `PasswordDeriveBytes.CryptDeriveKey`, even on Windows, unless you can assure the default CSP is (and will remain) identical across all computers running your application.

In conclusion, to avoid interoperability / security issues, I strongly suggest your to use the newer PKCS#5 v2, which Mono/MonoTouch/Microsoft implements as [`System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx).

Comment: thank you very much. I changed two lines in this method to `var pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, new byte[8]);
des.Key = pdb.GetBytes(16);
` . Is this best solution ?

Comment: Yes, it's fine - but you might want to hard code some other value (than an empty `byte` array).