# C# Cryptography generating a key

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to encrypt/decrypt a string using c#. I've found countless tutorials on how to this ex: [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/Cryptography_MD5_TriDES.aspx) However most of them assume you already have the key. So my question is:

How do I generate the key ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could ask the user for a pass phase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the encryption classes in the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace, use the [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) class (@CodeInChaos points out that it supersedes `PasswordDeriveBytes`) to derive a key from a password.

If a random key is OK, the [`SymmetricAlgorithm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) class has a `GenerateKey` method.

Comment: I'd favour `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx

Comment: @CodeInChaos, what's the TL;DR version of why you'd choose one over the other?

Comment: `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` is PBKDF2, `PasswordDeriveBytes` is PBKDF1. And I simply assume 2 is better than 1.

Comment: Fair enough; I looked into it a little more and decided to update the answer after seeing more references to the newer standard.

Comment: There are very good reasons to avoid PBKDF1 and even more how Microsoft implement (extended it) in `PasswordDeriveBytes`, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8459312/220643

Comment: @poupou Thanks for elaborating on that; very handy to know.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on you handle the keys.

If you automatically generate the key and just exchange the key over some channel with a key-exchange method then you should generate the key with some strong random number generator like [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx). Actually most Ciphers in .NET generate a random key automatically.

If you want to have some kind of user entered password then I suggest you to use the [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) class. There is also a Tutorial on the [.NET Security blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/04/14/113514.aspx) about `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`.

Answer (score 1):

Well depending on what key you want you can generate one here

http://randomkeygen.com/ or https://www.grc.com/passwords.htm

But what type of key are you after?