# How to create activate link for new user register in web ste using asp.net mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I just do Register form in my view, if the user register ready, field WebLog in my database set to -1, but for complete register, the user have to activate the link.

I want to get some idea, how to create that link in asp.net MVC.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this answer in SO.  It is about password reset but it applies exactly the same as the validation link.  Code is included so you can generate a link to do the validation.

You should use the Membership Provider which will handle all the details of storing the states, password resets, etc.

[Where to find C# sample code to implement password recovery in ASP .NET MVC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793108/where-to-find-c-sharp-sample-code-to-implement-password-recovery-in-asp-net-mvc/7796280#7796280)