# MVC 4 Password Recovery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, asp.net-mail

First I am quite new to MVC and I am trying to implement a password recovery functionality for MVC 4. I am implementing this using this technique posted here: [Where to find C# sample code to implement password recovery in ASP .NET MVC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793108/where-to-find-c-sharp-sample-code-to-implement-password-recovery-in-asp-net-mvc/13733194#13733194)

I understood the way it works however there is missing a helper class that I try to implement right now. I am talking about the class: **NotificationsHelper.SendPasswordRetrieval(model.Email, this.ControllerContext);**

The **RetrievePassword** acction controller on the controller has a parameter **PasswordRetrievalModel model**. I guess that this is a class model that connects to db and implements some properties among theme is a string property called **Email**. Is this correct?

Than, the **NotificationsHelper.SendPasswordRetrieval(model.Email, this.ControllerContext);** static class implements this static method **SendPasswordRetrievla** with 2 paramateres: **model.Email** that is the string property frrom the PasswordRetrievalModel model class, so this will be the user email to which we will send the email. Than the second parameter is **this.ControllerContext**. What is the point of this parameter what values will contain that are sent to the **SendPasswordRetrieval** method?

Than I implemented the class like this:

```
public static class NotificationsHelper
{
    public static bool SendPasswordRetrieval(string emailAddress, ControllerContext ctx)
    {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder emailMessage = new StringBuilder();

            emailMessage.Append("<br />");
            emailMessage.Append("Hello,");
            emailMessage.Append("You have requested a password recovery.");
            emailMessage.Append("<br />");
            emailMessage.Append("Please click the link below to change your password: <br />");
            emailMessage.Append("<br />");
            emailMessage.Append(string.Format("http://www.example.com/Account/Validate?email={0}&token={1}", emailAddress, "**345982374532453435345**"));
            emailMessage.Append("<br />");

            MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
            email.From = new MailAddress("noreplay@example.com");
            email.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailAddress));
            email.Subject = "domain.com Password Recovery";
            email.Body = emailMessage.ToString();
            email.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient();
            smtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtpServer.Port = 587;
            smtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpServer.Send(email);
            return true;
        }            
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("Failure to send email to {0}.", emailAddress));
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above I listed the line where the url is formatted, how do I bring there the token using the code @agarcian provided? Is the token coming from the second parameter **ControllerContext**? If yes how do i get it from there?

Answer (score 0):

Add new column for `usertable` name it `pwdresetTocket`, when user request  to reset password insert `Guid.NewGuid()` in pwdresetTocket field for that user, append the same in callback URL

if you don't want to add column to existing table, you can create a new table and map it to user Table.

Then your method looks like this.

```
public static bool SendPasswordRetrieval(string emailAddress, ControllerContext ctx)
    {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder emailMessage = new StringBuilder();
          string token = Guid.NewGuid();
        // call to a method that will update the table with token
        updateUsertablewithResetTocket(tocken);

            emailMessage.Append("<br />");
            emailMessage.Append("Hello,");
            emailMessage.Append("You have requested a password recovery.");
            emailMessage.Append("<br />");
            emailMessage.Append("Please click the link below to change your password: <br />");
            emailMessage.Append("<br />");
            emailMessage.Append(string.Format("http://www.example.com/Account/Validate?email={0}&token={1}", emailAddress, token));
            emailMessage.Append("<br />");

            MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
            email.From = new MailAddress("noreplay@example.com");
            email.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailAddress));
            email.Subject = "domain.com Password Recovery";
            email.Body = emailMessage.ToString();
            email.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient();
            smtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtpServer.Port = 587;
            smtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpServer.Send(email);
            return true;
        }            
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("Failure to send email to {0}.", emailAddress));
            return false;
        }
    }
```

once user resets the password, empty the reset token field